# Confusing pgbouncer exporter metric in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, pgbouncer

I have added 10 replicas of pgbouncer with prometheus [exporter](https://github.com/spreaker/prometheus-pgbouncer-exporter) as sidecar with a deployment manifest, and this grafana chart is showing the following prom query:

```
sort_desc( sum by (database, pod) ( rate(pgbouncer_stats_transactions_total{database=~"$db"}[1m]) ) )
```

I'm confused on why this metric keeps going up for 5 days straight, can you point me to what's wrong with the query.

[image]

[pgbouncer-exporter repo](https://github.com/spreaker/prometheus-pgbouncer-exporter)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

```
sum(rate(pgbouncer_stats_transactions_total{database=~"$db"}[$__rate_interval])) by (database)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).